# Hardware requirement for IOS compilation

Tags: ios, development, hardware-recommendation

My company is moving to IOS Apps development and we are looking for a MAC's pc to compile the apps.  Basically we will develop at Window workstation, then compile at MAC.

Is the Mac Book Pro i5 or Mac Mini i5 power enough the the apps compilation(will only run as workstation to compile the IOS apps)?

How about Running OSX at window 10 HyperV, is it support?

Thanks
Louis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a 13" retina MacBook Pro for writing applications (for iOS or OS X) in multiple languages with Xcode. I find that my computer is, more often than not, enough to compile an application for release from the command line.

Of course, the general rule that the more powerful your computer, the faster it will get stuff done applies, so it's a matter of how much you're willing to wait.

Depending on the size of your uncompiled application, compilation times can take anywhere from a few seconds to ten minutes.